# showip: command not found

Tags: bash, path

I am trying to run one of the example from Beej's Guide to Network Programming (https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/), specifically showip.c (The link to the program is here: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/showip.c). Using gcc, I've typed in

```
gcc -o showip showip.c
```

Then ran the program

```
showip www.example.net
```

and I get an error **showip: command not found** on the same directory where the code and the program is compiled at. I'm not sure why this is the case. I've even cloned the code from his GitHub and used makefile to compile the program and yet I'm getting the same error. What exactly am I doing it wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually problem with how you're running the program.

On Linux systems (unlike Windows systems) an executable in the current directory is not by default searched by the shell for programs to run.  If the given program does not contain a path element (i.e. there are no `/` characters in the name) then only the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable are searched.

Since the current directory is not part of your PATH, prefix the command with the directory:

```
./showip www.example.net
```

Comment: This is such a rookie mistake... but it did work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is the working directory on your path?  Likely not.

Try `./showip`

Answer (score -1):

Since the program `showip` is not in your `$PATH` you have to tell
your shell that it's in the current directory:

```
./showip
```

Or add the current directory to your `$PATH` but it's a less secure
option:

```
PATH=:$PATH
```

or

```
PATH=.:$PATH
```

and run it as you're trying now:

```
showip
```